# Clear values of controls dynamically

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I would like to know if there is a algoritm for clearing all the values dynamically of a Panel without the need to do it manually. And recursive if it 's possible. I have this idea in my mind but it doesn 't compile obviously.

```
    Private Sub ClearAll(ByRef panel As Control)

    For Each objControl As Control In panel.Controls

        If (TypeOf objControl Is Panel) Then
            ClearAll(objControl)
        End If

        If (TypeOf objControl Is CheckBox Or TypeOf objControl Is RadioButton) Then
            objControl.Checked = False
        End If

        If (TypeOf objControl Is TextBox) Then
            objControl.Clear()
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You have a loop so you dont need recursion (you only need to clear them once).  Then after you determine the control type, cast it: `CType(objControl, CheckBox).Checked = False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You're close!

- when you recurse, you don't have to check the type, all Control objects have .controls and it doesn't hurt to check them (speed gain isn't worth code bloat)
- In VB use CType.

Then you're done! (for clarity: rename the variable 'panel' to 'ctl' or the like; it now won't always be a panel, could be a groupbox)

```
Private Sub ClearAll(ByRef panel As Control)

  For Each objControl As Control In panel.Controls

    ClearAll(objControl)

    If TypeOf objControl Is Checkbox then
        ctype(objControl,Checkbox).Checked = False
    End If
    If TypeOf objControl Is RadioButton then
        ctype(objControl,RadioButton).Checked = False
    End If

    If TypeOf objControl Is TextBox Then
        ctype(objControl,textbox).Clear()
    End If

    ' etc ... e.g., if Listbox, ctype(...).SelectedIndex=-1, then if Dropdown...

  Next

End Sub
```

#### Ideally, winforms controls would implement simple interfaces that allowed controlling stuff common to them.

- all controls - implement ISetToDefault with .Reset method which clears textbox, checkbox, listbox, etc.
- list/combo: IHaveListItems with all properties of .List on combo/listbox to allow operating lists as single type (in wf, the two are frustratingly different types!)
- text/combo: IHaveUserEnteredText with a .Text property
- all controls - IHaveValue with a .Value property as string (would be .ToString of Boolean or etc).
- groupbox/check/option - IHaveCaption with .Caption, you get the idea.

#### But we don't get to rewrite winforms now do we...

Comment: @zaggler - I don't mean all controls actually have child controls. All objects of type 'control' have a .Controls property of type ControlCollection. For a textbox or non-container control, it will always have zero items. Function will recurse but the FOR will skip a/c Zero items in collection. This is expected behavior. More info about .Controls - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try this so you can add many region for exemple if you have TabControl or GroupeControle  :

```
 Public Shared Sub ClearChamps(ByVal myObject As Control)


        '#Region "Controls XtraTabControl"

        '#End Region

        '#Region "Controls XtraTabPage"

        ' #Region "Controls GroupControl"
        '****les controles de la GroupControl
        If TypeOf myObject Is Control Then
            Dim cont2 As Control = DirectCast(myObject, Control)

            For Each myObject1 As [Object] In cont2.Controls

                'If TypeOf myObject1 Is LookUpEdit Then
                '    '(myObject1 as LookUpEdit).ClosePopup() ;

                '    TryCast(myObject1, LookUpEdit).EditValue = Nothing
                If TypeOf myObject1 Is TextBox Then
                    TryCast(myObject1, TextBox).Text = String.Empty
                End If
                If TypeOf myObject1 Is DataGridView Then
                    myObject1.Rows.Clear()
                End If
                If (TypeOf myObject1 Is CheckBox Or TypeOf myObject1 Is RadioButton) Then
                    myObject1.Checked = False
                End If
            Next
        End If
        '  #End Region
        '#Region "Groupbox"
        '****les controles de la GroupControl

    End Sub
```

you can use ClearChamps(ByVal myObject As Form) for target all controls in your form